# loading very slowly all colors in htmll5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, performance, canvas

i am trying to make a color tools.so I i tried to show the colors in a canvas.But the problem is,it is loading very slowly.here is my code

```
  var l=0

  var ctx = document.getElementById('color').getContext('2d');
  for (var i=0;i<125;i++){
    for (var j=0;j<124;j++){
        for(var k=0;k<125;k++){
      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(' +i*2+ ',' +j*2 + ','+k*2+')';
      l=i+k; 
      ctx.fillRect(l*1,j*1,1,1);
    }
    }   
  }
```

i have tested it firefox and crome.Both shows the same behaviour.Please help me.thanks in advance.

Comment: Filling 126*125*126 1 pixel rectangles is a lot to do. You should rather create a predefined image, and use it as a map - get coordinates of clicks to define the exact color... (BTW, shouldn't that be `[i<|j<|k<]128` in the conditions for the for loops?)

Comment: Besides the fact that it's pretty fast for me (probably depends on the size of the canvas and the power of your computer) you are doing a for loop with 2million iterations, that takes a while. Also this seems to miss some colors.

Comment: This is an `O(MG)` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your algorithm is basically wrong. You are calculating the colors in a 3d space,  (i j k) and maping that on a 2d space (l, j).

Every value for the l variable is calculated several times and only the last one is visible (i=0 k=100 -> l=100 ; 1=1 k=99 > l=100; i=2 k=98 > l=100 ...

You should decide beforehand what colors go where, and have only 2 loops and not 3 (Probably the most usual decision here is going to a hsl space, omitting l and doing the loops on h and s.

The other big improvement would be to set pixels directly and do not use fillrect. Something in the line of:

```
var imgData=ctx.createImageData (125,125);

accesing pixels

ctx.putImageData(imgData,0,0);
```

Comment: Colors are in 3d space, since they are RGB.

Comment: @jedrus07 yes, of course, but the canvas is 2d. Usually a color picker has a 2d area and then a slider so that you can get the third dimension. So, when you are painting the 2d area, you are in 2d, not 3d.

Comment: My point is- the number of the loops will still be the same and the reason he iterates 3 times is just the fact that it is easier.

Answer (score 0):

You should have picture already precalculated (as one of the comments suggest) and then only read the position from this picture. From that you could reverse engineer your color in RGB.